Using awk inside of `find ... -exec bash -c`
I have a directory structure that looks like the following:
   .
   |-five
   |-four
   |-one
   |-seven
   |-six
   |-three
   |-two

Each of these subdirectories have files in them which are the output of uniq -c:
./five/failures.count
./four/failures.count
./one/failures.count
./six/failures.count
./three/failures.count
./two/failures.count
./seven/failures.count

What I'd like to do is to get the total count from each of these files all at the same time. So what I tried to do was:
find . -name "failures.count" -exec bash -c 'echo -n "$1: "; awk \'{n+=$1} END {print n}\' $1' bash {} \;

But this somehow has unbalanced quotes & waits for me to close it. What I want is for the awk command ({n+=$1} END {print n}) to also be single quoted so that the $1 within the awk command isn't expanded to the filename, which is the $1 argument to bash; the argument to bash is obviously single quoted, so I'm unsure how to spell that. I do know for sure that I'm not able to use double quotes like I'm doing for echo, but like I said, I'm unsure of how to manipulate the necessary single quotes to get this to work.

You cannot escape \' from inside a single-quoted string. You could briefly change to double quotes as in …'"'"'… but that's ugly. Better use double quotes and quote \$ instead. Or even better, have awk print the filename, so you can call it directly from find.

does each file have multiple counts? for the final output do you want a sum for each file or a single sum of all files combined?

Can any of the input files be empty? Can there be enough input files as to possibly exceed ARG_MAX? Some of the answers you have so far would fail if either answer is yes so it's important to state that in your question.

If one of the answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If you prefer, you are welcome to post an answer of your own, and accepting that. Accepting an answer helps future visitors by marking your problem as resolved. See also help.

You don't need find if the the files are all one subdirectory deep.
awk 'FNR==1 {
    if (NR>1) print f ": " n
    f = FILENAME; n=0 }
  { n+=$1 }
  END { print f ": " n }' ./*/failures.count

If you need to use bash -c in find you need to understand the shell's quoting rules.

Single quotes quote literally, so a backslash is just a literal backslash and a single quote always begins or ends the quoted string.
Double quotes are more flexible, but then you need to backslash-escape any literal backslash, dollar sign, backtick, or double quote.
There are also C-style $'...' strings in Bash, which are otherwise similar to single-quoted strings, but you can use C-style backslash escapes.

So a minimal fix might be
find . -name "failures.count" \
  -exec bash -c 'echo -n "$1: ";
        awk "{n+=\$1} END {print n}" "$1"' bash {} \;

(notice also the proper filename quoting)
though as already suggested in multiple answers, Awk can print the FILENAME itself just fine; and using find -exec with + instead of \; would be more efficient, at the expense of a slightly more complex Bash script.
find . -name "failures.count" \
  -exec bash -c $'for f; do
            awk \'{n+=$1} END {print FILENAME ": " n}\' "$f";
        done' bash {} +

(also demonstrating the use of a C-style string) though of course the Awk script we started with will be more efficient still, because that way we reduce the number of processes even further. Here's how to use it with find:
find . -name "failures.count" \
  -exec awk 'FNR==1 {
    if (NR>1) print f ": " n
    f = FILENAME; n=0 }
  { n+=$1 }
  END { print f ": " n }' {} +


With GNU awk for ENDFILE you could do:
find . -name 'failures.count' -exec awk '{n+=$1} ENDFILE{print FILENAME": "(n+0); n=0}' {} +

otherwise with any awk:
find . -name 'failures.count' -exec awk '{n[FILENAME]+=$1} END{for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) print ARGV[i]": "(n[ARGV[i]]+0)}' {} +

Using + instead of \; at the end of the find command will let find call awk once per [large] group of files instead of once per file which will speed up processing overall as it reduces the number of subshells being spawned to call awk.
The find is necessary if there are enough input files that you might exceed ARG_MAX and the (n+0) and loop on ARGV[] in the 2nd script are necessary if any input file could be empty,

You don't need bash there
find . -name failures.count -exec awk '{n+=$1} END{print FILENAME": "n}' {} \;



What I'd like to do is to get the total count from each of these files all at the same time.

this is a simple way to calculate the total count for all failures.count files
find . -name "failures.count" -exec bash -c 'echo -n "$1: "; awk '"'"'{n+=$1} END {print n}'"'"' "$1"' _ {} \;

